Change panel app shortcuts in Linux
All I would like to happen is when I right click Firefox in the Panel there will be an option to click which will open the profile list. I am using Linux Mint.
In Windows I configured it exactly the way I explained but after searching I don't see any way to do this on Linux. How can I modify the package to give me this option in the panel when right clicking Firefox?

Debian derivatives, such as Mint and Ubuntu, have an application that shows existing keyboard shortcuts, enables changing them, and allows new keyboard shortcuts to be added.

Press the System key (one with window icon).
Type keyb and select Keyboard app.
Select the Shortcuts tab.

Existing keyboard shortcuts, such as for screenshots, can be set to use different key combinations, or shortcuts can be removed (they can be added back later).
New shortcuts can be added:

For an existing application, just enter the app name (N.B.: Linux is case sensitive).
For a shortcut to a Windows application, just enter wine <full path to app>). For example, I use wine /WinApp/IrfanView/IrfanView32.exe on a Linux-only PC, and the path to IrfanView in the Windows NTFS folder on a dual-boot PC, avoiding having to reinstall the app for Ubuntu.
A shortcut can contain command-line arguments, such as for the wine environment or for an app.
A shortcut can run a system command, such as systemctl suspend to enter Sleep.

